# Do Sabre's lists of city pairs contain only few countries?

Tags: sabre

When I'm downloading the prod list of city pairs from here: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/instaflights_search

I see only us cities and canadian cities.

Don't they support searches for flights from other countries to other countries?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. If you check out the second sheet in the file you'd find cities like London, Munich and Tel Aviv.

Comment: But the origin or destination is only US city or German or Canadian.